# How is ASP.Net Routing accomplished given there is no obvious ISAPI mapping?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

So Im reading that:

> If a file name extension has not been mapped to ASP.NET, ASP.NET will
>   not receive the request. This is important to understand for
>   applications that use ASP.NET authentication. For example, because
>   .htm files are typically not mapped to ASP.NET, ASP.NET will not
>   perform authentication or authorization checks on requests for .htm
>   files. Therefore, even if a file contains only static content, if you
>   want ASP.NET to check authentication, create the file using a file
>   name extension mapped to ASP.NET, such as .aspx.

which I understand given the obvious .htm <> ASP.net ISAPI mapping in the webserver but what about routes in a route table? I'm not mapping those in the web server so how does the web server know to forward those URLs to ASP.Net??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are at least two pieces to this question:

The first is if you are running in `IIS` in `classic mode` versus `integrated mode`. `Classic mode` will make things behave like IIS 6, where everything is an `ISAPI filter`, including ASP.NET itself. `Integrated` mode takes advantage of the fact that IIS 7 was rewritten from the ground-up and now uses modules instead.

Secondly, the short answer of why `IIS` knows how to forward a `URL` to `ASP.NET` is the `Routing Module` in the IIS 7+ pipeline; `ISAPI filters` are now part of the `ISAPI Filters Module`.

For a visual description of how the IIS 7+ pipeline works from a `Routing/URL-Rewriting` perspective, read [IIS URL Rewriting and ASP.NET Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing)

So the good news is if you are very much attached to the `ISAPI filter` approach you can use the `classic mode` of `IIS`.